# Pull string value out of JSON object

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-services, json

I have a web service that returns me a JSON object that contains the string "Hello World". How do I pull this string out of the object?

data = [object Object]

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to know how is your object, what members the object have.

You could try something like

```
for(var e in data)
    alert(e + ' : ' + data[e]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `eval`:

```
var foo = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

But that is potentially dangerous, especially if you don't trust what is being sent from the server.  Thus, the best way (and most secure way) to extract data from a JSON object is by using [Crockford's   JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
var foo = JSON.parse(data);
```

---

Btw, if you're using jQuery to query ASP.Net Web Services, be careful of the the `d.` issue (which is used as a container object).  Thus to extract the returned object, you have to do:

```
var foo = JSON.parse(data);
if (foo) {
    //Foo is not null
    foo = f.d;
}
```

More information about this here: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery's post function you might follow this example found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post).

```
$.post("test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" },
    function (data) {
        alert(data.name); // John
        console.log(data.time); //  2pm
    }, "json");
```

In your case, I would suspect that you would call data.data.